# How to resolve android property not set when trying to upload app to the Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I am trying to upload my app to the Play Store but I get the error in the screenshot below
[image]

According to Google's suggestion, I added android:exported= "true" to my AndroidManifest.xml file. But after doing so the output is still the same. Please how do I fix this problem. Thank you

Here is a view of my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lds.jumbocheap">
    <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="JumboCheap"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this buiActivity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.sdk.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="#####" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

*check your minsdk and target sdk version*

**minSdkVersion 21**

**targetSdkVersion 30**